# Incorrect paths in icon font generated from SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, css, web-fonts

I have a collection of simple SVG icons exported from Illustrator. These contain just a `<path>` element to conform the icon itself and no borders. The original SVG format seems to be correct but within the generated font, the icon borderline seem to be broken; displaying sharp corners and irregular lines. To generate the font I'm using this script: https://github.com/nfroidure/gulp-iconfont.

Does someone know what could be causing this? Is this related with the CSS? The Illustrator export? Or how the font was created?

Here is the original SVG:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><title>users</title><g id="_973-user-toolbar_2x.png" data-name="973-user-toolbar@2x.png"><path d="M32.34,30.59A3.64,3.64,0,0,1,30,28.3c-.41-1.69,1.06-3.54,1.06-3.54h0c.11-.11,2-3.68,2-9.48C33,10.87,31.25,6,25,6s-8,4.87-8,9.29a21,21,0,0,0,1.91,9.42S20.41,26.6,20,28.3a3.63,3.63,0,0,1-2.35,2.29C8.62,33.4,3,34.71,3,37.25V40a2.15,2.15,0,0,0,2,2H45a2.15,2.15,0,0,0,2-2V37.25C47,34.71,41.38,33.4,32.34,30.59ZM45,39.91l-.09.09H5.09L5,39.91V37.34c.68-1,9.82-3.79,9.82-3.79s6.21-1.39,7.13-4.79c.55-2.3-.88-4.48-1.37-5.14A20,20,0,0,1,19,15.29C19,10.45,21,8,25,8s6,2.45,6,7.29a20.05,20.05,0,0,1-1.58,8.27l-.67,1.09a5.89,5.89,0,0,0-.71,4.12c.83,3.47,6,4.45,7.13,4.78,4.29,1.3,9.13,2.78,9.81,3.79Z"/></g></svg>
```

Here how it looks.

ORIGINAL SVG:

[image: ORIGINAL SVG]

FONT USED IN A WEB PROJECT:

[image: FONT USED IN A WEB PROJECT]

Comment: This looks like a path rounding issue or a "corner-type" error. Also bear in mind any calculated value that is not an even integer will be rounded so as to fall "on a pixel," and the smaller your typeface, the larger the impact such rounding will have. It would be interesting to see the original SVG as an SVG instead of a PNG. This might reveal something that Illustrator supports but is not strict SVG (etc).

Comment: I have edited the question and added the SVG code. It's not possible to attach svg files. As you can see, there are a lot of values that are not integers. Do you know if there is any way to optimise the SVG for font usage? should I try specifying the "corner-type" somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly a problem with the generated font.

The gulp-iconfont [README](https://github.com/nfroidure/gulp-iconfont/blob/master/README.md) says:

> **If some font glyphs aren't converted properly** you should add the `normalize:true` option and a fontHeight greater than 1000 (`fontHeight: 1001`).

Regarding the SVG, It also says:

> #### Preparing SVG's
>
> Beware that your SVG icons must have a high enough height. **500 is a minimum**. If you do not want to resize them, you can try to combine the `fontHeight` and the `normalize` option to get them in a correct size.
>
> ...
>
> Save your file as SVG with the following settings:
>
> - SVG Profiles: SVG 1.1
> - Fonts Type: SVG
> - Fonts Subsetting: None
> - Options Image Location: Embed
> - Advanced Options
>
>   - CSS Properties: Presentation Attributes
>   - Decimal Places: 1
>   - Encoding: UTF-8
>   - Output fewer elements: check

---

Your SVG is on a 50 × 50 viewbox so that is likely the problem. You should try regenerating the font with your SVG resized to a more appropriate size and/or try generating using some combination of `fontHeight` and `normalize` options.

You should try and reduce your SVG to the minimum needed too, so remove any unnecessary groups or elements.

This is your SVG resaved from Illustrator at 1000 × 1000:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="1000px" height="1000px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M646.8,611.8c-22-7-39.3-24-46.8-45.8c-8.2-33.8,21.2-70.8,21.2-70.8l0,0c2.2-2.2,40-73.6,40-189.6C660,217.4,625,120,500,120s-160,97.4-160,185.8c-2,64.9,11.1,129.4,38.2,188.4c0,0,30,37.8,21.8,71.8c-7.5,21.9-24.9,38.9-47,45.8C172.4,668,60,694.2,60,745v55c1.5,21.5,18.5,38.5,40,40h800c21.5-1.5,38.5-18.5,40-40v-55C940,694.2,827.6,668,646.8,611.8zM900,798.2l-1.8,1.8H101.8l-1.8-1.8v-51.4c13.6-20,196.4-75.8,196.4-75.8s124.2-27.8,142.6-95.8c11-46-17.6-89.6-27.4-102.8C389.3,419.8,378.5,363,380,305.8C380,209,420,160,500,160s120,49,120,145.8c1.3,56.7-9.5,113.1-31.6,165.4L575,493c-14.7,24.8-19.7,54.1-14.2,82.4c16.6,69.4,120,89,142.6,95.6c85.8,26,182.6,55.6,196.2,75.8L900,798.2z"/>
</svg>
```

---

*Note, I've never used gulp-iconfont so am only going off the instructions in the README.*

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where it says that the height should be 500 at least. Both solutions scaling the svg or fontHeight: 1001 and normalize: solves the problem